# How can i become OTA provider and do XML sync with PMS for hotel, Channel manager system?

Tags: calendar, synchronization, filesystems, icalendar, platform

We are developing our hotel management system (PMS) for our hotel. There are a number of questions:

An example is the site booking.com. He has his own calendar for managing the hotel's load and prices. This calendar has the possibility of sending to the PMS system through the XML calendar. In the choice of admin panel booking.com as a hotel manager there is a PMS selection functionality which to send the calendar synchronization with booking.com. There are about 300 of them.

And on the other hand in the PMS of the external platform there is a choice of sales channels, such sites as booking.com and others. And when I send the calendar synchronization with booking.com to the PMS system there is a choice also inside the PMS system online travel agency Booking.com.

Total questions:

1. How can I become an aggregator as a booking.com site so that we can be selected in PMS systems as an aggregator channel.
2. How can I unload my calendar in two third-party mode. Through XML, what are the other options? How does this work?

Comment: Is it solved? @Stanislav Mandrik

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you clearly but if you want to be able to sync with booking.com

1. you have to register as affiliate partner with booking.com
2. then you can request for developer page access
3. once you get the access for developer page, you can get an API Key and you can see the full XML API documentation.

Then you can start developing 2 way request and responses according to their document.

For starters, I will recommend Agoda or HomeAway.com

Comment: Hi PyOrion, do you have link where we can register and get approval for the request with Agoda.com? I cannot find anywhere how to get the access with Agoda.com